# ¿Còmo dejar vacio un pipe en C?

Tags: c, pipe

Estoy trabajando con pipes en C, y lo que entiendo es:

1. Lo que se lee de un pipe se consume
2. Si se trata de leer de un pipe vacio el proceso se queda esperando a que se introdusca algo en el pipe para leerlo.

pero al correr este còdigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd[2], valor, valor2, i = 0;
    pipe(fd);
    valor = 10;

    write(fd[1],&valor,sizeof(int));
    close(fd[1]);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        read(fd[0],&valor2,sizeof(int));
        printf("El numero %d es: %d\n", i,valor);
    }
    close(fd[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

El ciclo se completa sin bloquearce.

¿No deberia de bloquearce al intentar la segunda iteración? (ya que se supone se consumiò lo que se habia escrito)

Si no es el caso, entonces ¿Cùal es la manera correcta de dejar un pipe vacio?